# Query Overpass API for roads in a specific country

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to construct a query of all 'highway=' ways in a specific area in overpass. I've been defaulting to using the {{bbox}} - but I really would prefer to do it by country.

I've tried using 'nominatimArea:' instead of {{bbox}} but I get a parse error ' line 8: parse error: ')' expected - '(' found. ' on the below:

```
/*
This shows the roads in nepal.
*/

[out:json];

(
  way ["highway"~"motorway|trunk|primary|motorway_link|trunk_link|primary_link|unclassified|tertiary|secondary|track|path"]({{nominatimArea:Nepal}});
);

out meta;
>;
out skel qt;
```

ALSO ... if I try this...I only (weirdly) get one area - no ways (maybe the relations are a mess?)

```
/*
This shows the roads in nepal.
*/

[out:json];

(area[name="Nepal"];
  way(area) ["highway"~"motorway|trunk|primary|motorway_link|trunk_link|primary_link|unclassified|tertiary|secondary|track|path|residential|service"];
);

out meta;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Returns this [one item](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out%3Ajson]%3B%28area[%22name%22%3D%22Nepal%22]%3Bway%28area%29[%22highway%22~%22motorway%7Ctrunk%7Cprimary%7Cmotorway_link%7Ctrunk_link%7Cprimary_link%7Cunclassified%7Ctertiary%7Csecondary%7Ctrack%7Cpath%7Cresidential%7Cservice%22]%3B%29%3Bout%20meta%3B%3E%3Bout%20skel%20qt%3B%0A) (and it is an area NOT a way)

Note: I know this is a large query - but I really just need the url to the raw JSON (like [this](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json][timeout:25];%28node[%22building%22=%22yes%22]%2827.51314343580719,84.4683837890625,28.62551444875789,85.91720581054688%29-%3E.cr;node[%22building%22=%22damaged%22]%2827.51314343580719,84.4683837890625,28.62551444875789,85.91720581054688%29;node[%22building%22=%22collapsed%22]%2827.51314343580719,84.4683837890625,28.62551444875789,85.91720581054688%29;%29;out%20meta;%3E;out%20skel%20qt;)) - not the actual overpass map result.

Answer (score 9):

Got it.

```
/*
This shows the roads in nepal.
*/

[out:json];

area[name="नेपाल"];
 (way["highway"~"motorway|trunk|primary|motorway_link|trunk_link|primary_link|unclassified|tertiary|secondary|track|path|residential|service|secondary_link|tertiary_link"](area);
);

out meta;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Answer (score 0):

A modification to [user14696's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30227279/724406) as usually difficult to use local names. It would be more convenient to use your own language or English which most countries already had it set.

#### Use specific language tag and administrative level filter

```
[out:json];
    
area["name:en"="Nepal"][admin_level=2];
//area["name:en"="Gandaki Province"][admin_level=4];
//area["name"="Waling"][admin_level=7];
(
  way["highway"~
    "motorway|trunk|primary|
      |motorway_link|trunk_link|primary_link|
      |unclassified|tertiary|secondary|
      |track|path|residential|service|
      |secondary_link|tertiary_link|
      "]
    (area);
);
    
out meta;
>;
out skel qt;
```

#### Notes

- Some places have missing tags and some may have specific way of naming like dual language and triple language. So specific language `name:xxx` may more helpful then local `name` tag.
- In many places, same town name is used multiple administrative levels, so it is good to filter by `admin_level` too.
- Some queries are very heavy, may be fast to try on small area at the start.
- Keep OpenStreetMap page open, and look for tag which may help or may be contribute missing tags. For example: [Waling](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/10521984) has only `name` tag and it is in English. while many other tags with [Nepal](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/184633) (anyway, it is a country level)